# Axios : Add validateStatus hook to get HTTP 304 response

Tags: vue.js, axios

I’m trying to edit the validateStatus function of axios to get the response from an HTTP 304, I have tried a lot of methods found on Stack Overflow but none of them seems to work, I tried :

In the create :

```
axios.create({
  validateStatus: (status) => {
    return status >= 200 && status <= 304;
  },
});
```

In my get request :

```
return axios.get(`${FETCH_IDENTITY_URL}`, {
  validateStatus: (status) => {
    return status >= 200 && status <= 304;
  },
})
.then(response => response.data);
```

Do you have an exemple to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried putting some console logging inside your `validateStatus` function? I suspect it is being called but I'd be surprised if the `status` is actually 304. If the browser receives 304 it'll just use the cached response instead, so I would expect that you'll get the status code from that cached response and not the 304 status. Logging should confirm.

Comment: Yes I have tried to console.log in my validateStatus function but there is no log in the console :/
I see in network that the browser actually receives a 304,but it doesn't use cached response because by default, the validateStatus function of axios returns an error if HTTP status isn't between 200 and 300

Comment: I tried both of the code samples you provided and included some logging inside them. Both of them worked fine. If you can't see the logging then you really need to address that first before you do anything else. Make sure you have saved the files, refreshed the browser, etc.. Also check you don't have any filters turned on in the console. Put some console logging just before you make the request, that'll help confirm you aren't seeing a cached file.

Comment: I also did some further testing with 304 responses. In cases where the browser has a suitable cached response it will just use that instead. By the time axios sees the response the status code will already have been changed to the status code from the cached response, so `validateStatus` won't see the 304. The only time the browser exposes the 304 directly is if it doesn't have a suitable cached entry. This suggests that the server is at fault for returning 304 in the first place, which is why axios treats it as an error.

Comment: I tried to log directly in validateStatus function of node_modules/axios/lib/defaults.js, as you said earlier it log a 200 response so the error must be elsewhere, thanks for your help.

Comment: I also try to catch error from my request like this :
```
return axios.get(`${FETCH_IDENTITY_URL}`)
.then(response => response.data)
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

It log "Error: Network error" and nothing else

Comment: To debug further I suggest checking the *'Pause on caught exceptions'* checkbox in the developers tools just before you initiate the request. It should pause in the debugger when the promise is rejected, allowing you to see exactly what was going on at that point.